# UIBezierPaths are not kept on screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibezierpath

I have a custom UIView and in the drawRect method I create a UIBezierPath and render it to the screen. The issue I am having is that the previous UIBezierPath is removed from the view on the next drawRect call?

How can I keep all of these UIBezierPaths on screen?

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];

    // Move to centre and draw an arc.
    [path moveToPoint:self.center];
    [path addArcWithCenter:self.center
                radius:self.radius
            startAngle:self.startAngle
              endAngle:self.endAngle
             clockwise:YES];

    [path closePath];

    path.usesEvenOddFillRule = YES;

    [self.colorToRender setFill];
    [path fill];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever `drawRect:` is called you have to draw the whole screen of content. You can't append new drawings to what's already there. So you need to store the whole list of beziers and draw all of them.

Store them in an array and then loop over the array and draw each.

Also, you shouldn't really be creating new beziers in `drawRect:`...

Comment: What if each one is rendered inside a new layer in the view? I will have 174 renders in 7 seconds, so performance is the main issue here.

Comment: if you don't have to don't draw them in new layers, have a single layer and add new paths to that layer. creating new layers each time leads to awful performance.

Comment: Sure, that will work. Render each new bezier you have into the layer and then draw the layer.

Comment: @Wain - Apple's Core Graphics document has an example that creates UIBezierPaths in drawRect when I browsed through the UIBezierPath section.

Comment: Apple don't always follow their own rules or best practice during examples (or template code). drawRect: is for drawing, you shouldn't be updating your model (stored data) there. In your case, the bezier points and part of your stored data.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is the most convenient way but you have to keep reference to old paths and then combine the new one with them.

```
CAShapeLayer * shapeLayer; //Sublayer of your view
CGMutablePathRef combinedPath = CGPathCreateMutableCopy(shapeLayer.path);

CGMutablePathRef linePath = CGPathCreateMutable();

//Create your own custom linePath here

//No paths drawn before
if(combinedPath == NULL)
{
    combinedPath = linePath;
}
else
{
    CGPathAddPath(combinedPath, NULL, linePath);
}
shapeLayer.path = combinedPath;
CGPathRelease(linePath);
```

Comment: Does CGPathCreateMutableCopy automatically combine paths from an array?

Comment: imagine oldPaths = combinedPath at the very end, that's how data flows in my code snippet. actually it is better if edit my code

Comment: since you mentioned using layers i will update it including layer properties.

Comment: Great thanks, will wait for your updates. I was wondering, does the path retain the color or will I need an array of colors to apply to the array of paths?

Comment: I think I made a mistake telling it retains, I looked at my code and I created different layers for shape layers with different properties

Comment: Thanks guenis, I will try this. On another note, I am starting to learn audio signal processing and I see you are into DSP too, could you recommend any other tools other than MATLAB for visualising audio signals?

Comment: regarding your answer, will UIBezierPaths work with your example? e.g.  // Create your own linepath - I want to create a bezierPath like in my drawRect method.

Comment: please see my updated comment about coloring. sorry I can't help you on that one, I'm not much into audio processing, but have a look at the other popular tools like octave, scilab they are free.

Comment: no you can't add uibezierpaths but should be easy with UIBezierPath.CGPath

Comment: Im confused now with the different elements. I would like to use BezierPaths, and the layering was just a question. I don't need to use e.g. shapeLayer then. When I use UIBezierPath with the CGMutablePathRef I get back receiver type errors on e.g moveToPoint

Comment: I get a bunch of warnings that look troublesome. E.g. the oldPaths array will need to hold bezierPath.CGPaths right? I cannot add them to an array as they are not of object type.

Comment: you don't keep them in an array, oldPaths or shapeLayer.path is CGMutablePathRef or CGPathRef. These classes can hold multiple paths

Comment: if it is looking too troublesome, go for Wain's solution. Hold UIBezierPaths in an array, traverse the array and draw them

Comment: Thanks for the help. I hold them in an array and run through them. It feels overkill to rerender everything over and over. 127 rendered segments in 7 seconds. There is a lot of wasted rendering going on.